# MVC simple insert not updating database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, dbcontext

The is driving me nuts. Im trying to do a "simple" record insert and I can only get it to work if I store the context in a variable or create a local context. I tried to keep the context and model object tied together but no luck so far.

```
public class TransactionDataAccessLayer
{        
    public cartableContext transactionContext
    {
        get
        {                
            return new cartableContext();
        }
    }
}



class TransactionBusinessLayer
{       
    Cardata newCar = new Cardata();
    public void addCar(Cardata cd)
    {
        try
        {

            //this works. Storing the context in ctc2 seems to make it work???
            TransactionDataAccessLayer tdal = new TransactionDataAccessLayer();
            cartableContext ctc2 = tdal.transactionContext;
            ctc2.cardata.Add(cd);
            ctc2.SaveChanges();

            //this does not work
            tdal.transactionContext.cardata.Add(cd);                
            tdal.transactionContext.Entry(cd).State = EntityState.Modified;                
            tdal.transactionContext.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would that work if you return a new context every time you access the `transactionContext` property? All those actions should happen over the same context which is why the other approach works. In MVC you typically have a context per request.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, properties are basically just fancy methods, designed to make it easier to access private fields. Therefore, returning a new Context in your getter will do just that; return a *new* one each time it is accessed. To preserve state, you need to contain your context in a private field, like so:

```
public class TransactionDataAccessLayer
{   
    private cartableContext _transactionContext;
    public cartableContext transactionContext
    {
        get
        {   
            if (_transactionContext == null)
               _transactionContext = new cartableContext();
            return _transactionContext;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @tereško thanks for the response from both. Please forgive but, now I am really confused. I thought the context gets flushed after every response so you would need a fresh context to go with model objects?? Should the context persist across all responses?

Comment: Also transactionBUsinessLayer (TBL) is run from the controller's addCar method. Should this be moved outside so the TBL persists? I am still missing what the difference is between the code bites inside TBL above. I thought the only difference is the context is being stored in a variable after it is passed in?